# Use stored procedure in Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I want to use in a `SELECT` like below but I get an error.

The stored procedure's output is a table with one column of type `int`

```
select * from users where resCode in (EXEC getUserResselers 1)

-- stored procedure
create procedure getUserResselers
    @userCode int
as
    ;WITH Directories AS (SELECT  code FROM Resseler WHERE code =(select resselerCode from Users where code=@userCode)
    UNION ALL SELECT d.code FROM Resseler d INNER JOIN Directories p ON  d.parent = p.code)
        SELECT  * FROM    Directories d
```

Comment: Any reason it can't be a function instead?

Comment: no but i don't know how to use it and search in google and find sth but occur error, if you can solve this problem with function please help

Comment: And exactly **WHAT** is the error you're getting? Please post the full, complete and exact error - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct selection from a stored procedure is not supported. However, this type of operation is a good candidate for a [table-valued user-defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which might look something like:

<sup>*Note that you have misspelled "resellers". I've left the misspelling so that you could test with your existing schema.*</sup>

```
CREATE FUNCTION getUserResselers
(
    @UserCode INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN(
    WITH Directories AS (

       SELECT  code FROM Reseller WHERE code = (select resselerCode from Users where code=@userCode)
       UNION ALL SELECT d.code FROM Resseler d INNER JOIN Directories p ON  d.parent = p.code
    )
    SELECT  * FROM   Directories
)
```

You could then include a join to the function in your query, or you could continue to use `IN`, which should be something like:

```
select * from users where resCode in (SELECT Code FROM getUserResselers(1));
```